# implementing http authorization header in c

Tags: c, apache, http, header

am trying to implement a http (GET request) on c programming that include an authorization header but the the problem is that i can't get the (200 ok), i got only one session of communication (the server reply with 401 authorization required) but not more than that.

```
**while(1){

    strcpy(buffer,"GET /mywebsite/login.html/ HTTP1.1 \n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Host: localhost\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Connection: keep-alive\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q=0.8\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\n\n");
    status = send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if(status == -1) {
        printf("Error in send(). Error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        continue;
    }
    buffer[0]='\0';
    //The receiving functions
    status = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    if (status == -1) {
        printf("Error in recv(). Error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        continue;
    }
    buffer[status] = '\0';
    printf("The message received is: ");
    printf("%s\n\n", buffer);

    strcpy(buffer,"GET /mywebsite/login.html/ HTTP1.1\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Host: localhost\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Authorization: Basic QWRtaW46MTIzNA== \n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q=0.8\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\n\n");
    strcat(buffer,"Connection: keep-alive\n\n");
    status = send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if(status == -1) {
        printf("Error in send(). Error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        continue;
    }
    buffer[0]='\0';
    //The receiving functions
    status = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    if (status == -1) {
        printf("Error in recv(). Error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        continue;
    }
    buffer[status] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n\n", buffer);
    buffer[0]='\0';

}**
```

the first header is sent successfully, but the next header where the server keep doing nothing (no reply)
please little help here i dont have any clue of what the problem is ... :(

Comment: You should make sure you can perform the request manually (i.e. write out the HTTP requests by hand).  Then compare them to the text that your code produces.

Comment: And if that works, try using a tool like Fiddler to see the traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some obvious problems:

- Headers should be separated by "\r\n", not "\n\n", finally ending with "\r\n\r\n".
- `send` and `recv` should be retried on errno==EINTR
- `send` may send less bytes than requested, so it should be used in a loop to ensure all data are transferred.

Comment: And the code should make sure that the server did keep the connection alive as desired.

Comment: Am very thankful folks i had nightmares because of that program, and seeing that (200 ok) is really delight moment so thank you.